# dbt cli run - only project pre or post hooks?

Tags: command-line-interface, dbt

Is there a way to use the dbt cli to run my project's hooks without running any models?

i.e.

```
dbt run --post-hooks
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a macro you want to run in isolation from the rest of the resources in your project, you may want to look into [operations](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/hooks-operations/#operations):

```
dbt run-operation my_macro
```

Comment: This is not working on my project, I have a macro that is run tested on prehook but cannot run with run-operation. any tips? Jeremy@

Comment: If your hooks are running SQL against the database, you will need to wrap that SQL in `run_query` or `statement` blocks in order to execute them in a run-operation. (The difference? Hooks expect to take whatever strings are passed into them and execute it as SQL. `run-operation` doesn't bake in that same assumption.)